# VirtualBox Bridged Network to Debian Fails to connect

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, bridge

I am running Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager v4.2.0 r80737 on Microsoft Windows 7 and aiming to set up a bridged network to my Debian Linux 6.0 Virtual Machine to be able to connect to it via Local Network and to have Internet access on it. It was working correctly yesterday, but today it failed.

When I use the command `ifup eth0`, it keeps waiting for the DHCP. It outputs:

```
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
NO DHCPOFFERS received.
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains the following code:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is internet access in the guest machine, **NAT** will work out-of-the-box, no need for a bridge. You can use that together with **Shared Forlders** for sharing files between the host and the quest OS.

If you really want a bridge, e.g. you want to appear as two different hosts for other systems in your local network, while still being able to ssh to the guest, you should probably set up a bridge though. If VirtualBox Manager won't do it to you automatically, you can bridge the virtual NIC associated with your guest OS with another network interface in Network Adapter Settings on your host OS (check to see first if they are already birdged).

If you're still not getting any DHCP offers on the guest OS, try to set an IP manually and then ping your DHCP server (e.g. your router or modem), also from the guest OS, to see if you can access the network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In which network does my guest OS need to be if I would try to set up a static IP? The same network as my Host? Or does bridging create a different network?

Comment: Bridging will use the same network, it does not create a different network. So if your router/modem is 192.168.1.1, your host OS is, say, 192.168.1.2, you can set the guest OS to 192.168.1.3 and then try network access.

Comment: It worked! However, other computers on the same local network are not able to ping me. Do you know why?

Comment: @user907560 that's odd, do you see the network bridge in Network Adapter Settings in your Windows 7 host? Check its properties to see if maybe ICMP packets are being blocked somehow. (I assume you're using the bridge mode, not NAT, right?)

Comment: Not sure where to find settings regarding ICMP. My VirtualBox Host-Only Network is on a different network (192.x.x.x) than the Guest OS and my Host OS though (145.x.x.x). Should I enabled Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)?

Comment: @user907560 if you enable ICS, that may help you get Internet connection in the guest OS, but since your host is Windows, it will require you to set the host-only network adapter's IP to `192.168.0.1` (at least that was the case with Windows XP). If you want access from other machines on your network, you should probably go with bridged interfaces instead.

Comment: Yes, I am using a bridged connection at the moment. The Host is able to ping the Guest OS and the Guest OS is able to ping all computers on the network and the Internet. All other users except for the Host are unable to ping the Guest OS.

Comment: @user907560 that's very odd indeed. Since PING works from from the Guest OS to other computers on the network, that would mean that two-way communication is working, so something is blocking ICMP (and probably others too) from reaching the Guest OS from other parts of the local network. Did you check the firewall settings in your Host OS?

Comment: I did. The firewall is completely disabled.